# Save an array from array of arrays under some condition

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array of arrays and I want to save all the records whose last element is equal to zero. How can I do this? I have something like this.

```
array([[-0.88420819, -1.01983669,  1.12353698, ..., -2.18137332,
         1.12353698,  3.        ],
       [ 0.55632749, -1.97404661,  0.79290805, ..., -0.83084723,
         0.79290805,  0.        ],
       [-1.17401272, -3.25402615, -1.55695256, ..., -1.08043287,
        -1.55695256,  0.        ]
```

so I want to save the second and third record.

Comment: That's not valid code. And with fewer digits and without the ellipses it would be a nicer example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Conditionals in List Comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension).

```
old_array = [
  [-0.88420819, -1.01983669, 1.12353698, -2.18137332, 1.12353698,  3],
  [ 0.55632749, -1.97404661, 0.79290805, -0.83084723, 0.79290805, 0],
  [-1.17401272, -3.25402615, -1.55695256, -1.08043287, -1.55695256,  0]
]

new_array = [x for x in old_array if x[-1] == 0]

print(new_array)

# output:
# [[0.55632749, -1.97404661, 0.79290805, -0.83084723, 0.79290805, 0],
# [-1.17401272, -3.25402615, -1.55695256, -1.08043287, -1.55695256, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest and most practical way would be to use list comprehension and create a new list. After this you can convert it back to an array.

replace `arr` with your array name

```
arr = [[-0.88420819, -1.01983669,  1.12353698, -2.18137332,
         1.12353698,  3.        ],
       [ 0.55632749, -1.97404661,  0.79290805, -0.83084723,
         0.79290805,  0.        ],
       [-1.17401272, -3.25402615, -1.55695256, -1.08043287,
        -1.55695256,  0.        ]]

res = [val for val in arr if val[-1] == 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save it to a new variable, you can do:

```py
saved_array = []
for x in given_array:
    if x[-1] == 0:
        saved_array.append(x)
```

An alternate short form would be:

```py
saved_array = list(filter(lambda x: x[-1]==0, given_array))
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the out-of-NumPy detour of the other answers:

```
>>> a[a[:,-1] == 0]
array([[0.55632749, -1.97404661, 0.79290805, Ellipsis, -0.83084723,
        0.79290805, 0.0],
       [-1.17401272, -3.25402615, -1.55695256, Ellipsis, -1.08043287,
        -1.55695256, 0.0]], dtype=object)
```